# Implementing a post-save logic by overriding save_related in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

There is some related posts, but none of them is actually specific to this problem.

I'm trying to implement a post-save logic in one of my nested Django admin form. By nested I mean having inlines. I've been able to implement a logic by overriding `save_model` like so,

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    #Added logic here using obj
    return super(SomeModelAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Obviously, if changes were made in one of the inlines, my logic was not considering it since `save_model`is applied only on the parent object. I found a Django [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13950) on this issue. It suggest that `save_related` should be used instead since it now handles this kind of problem (see [this](https://github.com/django/django/commit/332a485567)).

Therefore I tried,

```
def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
    #Added logic here using form.instance
    return super(SomeModelAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
```

But I have the same behavior as above where changes seems not to be saved when using my logic. Is there something I'm doing wrong here ?

**EDIT**

Here is some more information. Basically, I'm adding a custom button in `change_form.html` and that is trigerring a custom method. So,

```
def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
    if 'MyButton' in request.POST:
    #Added logic here using form.instance
    return super(SomeModelAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
```

So, by doing this I'm adding a new custom behavior to django admin besides the built-in saves methods already included. In order words, the button could be used to manipulate data and save the model simultaneously.

Now, my problem is that when `MyButton` is triggered and custom logic is called, if someone has made changes in one of the inlines, the logic added does not consider it since it is not saved in the database yet.

Comment: Can you add some more code and examples? It's unclear what the expected outcome and the actual (unwanted) outcome is.

Comment: Well, there is not much more code I can provide. The expected outcome is to manipulate `obj` in situation 1 and `form.instance` in situation 2 (which are the same) after all model present in the form are saved. So, I want to overide the correct save method. From what I found `save_related` is called after saving all models including inlines instances.

Comment: @HåkenLid updated question.

Comment: @HåkenLid is it still unclear to you ?

Comment: What is the custom logic in `save_related`? It would be easier to understand if you included a complete example. [mcve]

Why don't you just do `super().save_related()` first, and then the custom logic? This method always returns `None`, so you don't need to have an explicit return statement. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/contrib/admin/options/#ModelAdmin.save_related

Comment: @HåkenLid Wow this was the solution! Thanks a lot ! You want to post answer and I will accept it or I will write an answer. I think this can happen to several other users in the future.

Comment: That's nice. I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: @HåkenLid Can you please elaborate on the `super.save_related` call also. You said that _This method always returns None, so you don't need to have an explicit return statement_ what do you mean by that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the custom logic must happen after the related objects have been saved, you can simply do it after calling the `super()` method.

```
class SomeModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    def save_related(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save_related(request, *args, **kwargs)

        if 'MyButton' in request.POST:
            #Added logic here using form.instance
```

Since you are using python 3, you don't need to pass any arguments to super(). Also, since `ModelAdmin.save_related` always returns `None`, you don't need a return statement in your `save_related`, either.

Comment: I will accept since it works, but it would be awsome if you could explain: _Since you are using python 3, you don't need to pass any arguments to super()_ and why do you say that _ModelAdmin.save_related always returns None, you don't need a return statement in your save_related, either._

Comment: In python3, the you can call the builtin `super()` with no arguments. If you write code that must work with python2 as well, you need to call it with `super(SomeModelAdmin, self)`. Since the upcoming version of django doesn't support python 2.7 at all, you might as well write code for python 3.x only.

Comment: If you read the source for `ModelAdmin.save_related`, you'll see that it doesn't have a `return' statement. It will always return `None'. So when you override the method in your subclass, you can just return `None` as well. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/contrib/admin/options/#ModelAdmin.save_related